# Dictionary vs Hashtable memory usage

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashtable

I've read here at SO that Hashtable and Dictionary are pretty much the same except for the advantages of avoiding boxing/unboxing.

Using the Ants Profiler I measure a very simple app with the following structures:

```
class Node
{
    Dictionary<string, Node> Children = new Dictionary<string, Node>();
}
```

and

> ```
>     class NodeOld
>     {
>         Hashtable Children = new Hashtable();
>     }
> ```

Ok, a list of 1.5Million instances of the first takes about 140Mb, while the second needs more than 700Mb (64bits system).

So, there's a HUGE difference in implementation, isn't it?

The Ants Profiler unveils a HUGE number of Hashtable+Bucket objects on the big-sized example...

So, is there an equivalent (memory-savvy) option for Dictionaries if you've to stick to 1.1?

Comment: I suspect that Dictionary is implemented using a self-balancing binary tree rather than a hash-table.  Also, is the memory consumption you found after garbage collection or just total accumulated?  As the Hashtable resized itself (as more and more elements were added), it would likely create more and more Buckets (though the older ones would be eligible for collection.)

Comment: for the hashtable that usees 700MB, are a lot of the buckets empty?

Comment: This describes the internal implementation of .net HashTable and Dictionary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Dan, `Dictionary<K,V>` *is* implemented as a hash table. `SortedDictionary<K,V>` is a binary search tree.

Comment: Yes, the memory is there after GC.

Comment: And yes, I bet most of the buckets are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if I am stuck on .NET 1.1 I wouldn't be storing 1.5 million instances into memory, so I wouldn't care about. Hashtable is probably the best data structure implementing a hash-table you could get in terms of memory consumption and speed in .NET 1.1. Of course if you explained your scenario in a more details and that you have identified that Hashtable is actually a bottleneck for your application there might be some better solutions.