# hash table memory usage for small number of items C#

Tags: c#, memory, dictionary, hashtable

I was wondering if having lots of small Dictionary wastes memory because of the overhead involved. Dictionary is implemented as a hash table, so if I have thousands of objects that each contain these small dictionaries don't I end up wasting a lot of space as opposed to just having a list/binary search tree that I search through, especially if each small dictionary only contains 4-5 key value pairs?

The code I am looking at now is implemented like that, and since there are memory issues I was wondering how wasteful it is to use hash tables for small number of items. What are my other options besides list/binary search trees?

Comment: Have you used a profiler to prove where the bottlenecks are? That would help immensely.

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarking is the best way to see performance vs. memory issues, of course, but if each dictionary will be that small, consider the [ListDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.listdictionary.aspx) or [HybridDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.hybriddictionary.aspx) classes. For small dictionaries you should definitely see a performance benefit and I suspect you will see a size benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you need the hashing functionality you could use a hastable instead of a dictionary, if not some lightweight collection will do. you can check out this link [Dictionary vs Hashtable memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740205/dictionary-vs-hashtable-memory-usage)